# How to connect more tables in mySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, visual-studio, xampp

Can someone show me how that connects more to the table where I set only has one and I need to override button can be opened more ...The user should choose the push of a button you will choose the table ...

```
    <?php



//include("connection.php");

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="vaktija";
$tbl_name="table 1";

// Connect to server and select databse.

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");



$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<html>


<body bgcolor="#f5fff5">
<div align="center" </div>
<br>
<br>
<b>Vaktija za SBK</b>
<br>
<br>

<div align="left" </div>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
<strong><a href="main_page.php" >  Back to main </a> </strong>
<br>
<br>


</html>

<?php


echo "<table width='1100' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#99FF33'>

<tr>
<th>Dan</th>
<th>Zora</th>
<th>Izlazak Sunca</th>
<th>Podne</th>
<th>Ikindija</th>
<th>Aksam</th>
<th>Jacija</th>


</tr>";

$color="1";

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
  if($color==1){

  echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>

<td>".$rows['Dan']."</td><td>".$rows['Zora']."</td><td>".$rows['Izlazak Sunca']."</td><td>".$rows['Podne']."</td><td>".$rows['Ikindija']."</td><td>".$rows['Aksam']."</td><td>".$rows['Jacija']."</td>
</tr>";

  $color="2";
}


else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>


<td>".$rows['Dan']."</td><td>".$rows['Zora']."</td><td>".$rows['Izlazak Sunca']."</td><td>".$rows['Podne']."</td><td>".$rows['Ikindija']."</td><td>".$rows['Aksam']."</td><td>".$rows['Jacija']."</td>
</tr>";

$color="1";
}
}

echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);

?>



<html>


<br>
<br>
<br>


</html>
```

Comment: To query a _different_ table, construct '$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`";' based on user input.  To query _multiple_ tables at the same time, learn about `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

A simple example can be: You have

```
Table 1
+----+-------+----------+
| id | name  | lastname |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Peter | Smith    |
|  2 | Susan | Johnson  |
+----+-------+----------+
```

And Table 2

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+
| id |   address    |    city     | state |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | 111 NE 11st. | Manhattan   | NY    |
|  2 | 222 NW 22st. | Long Island | NY    |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

If you run this query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table1 as t1
        JOIN
    table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

You will get **Table1+Table2**

```
+----+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-------------+----+
| id | name  | lastname id | address |     city     |    state    |    |
+----+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-------------+----+
|  1 | Peter | Smith       |       1 | 111 NE 11st. | Manhattan   | NY |
|  2 | Susan | Johnson     |       2 | 222 NW 22st. | Long Island | NY |
+----+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-------------+----+
```

**NOTE** This is just a dummy example, just for illustrate the answer